# php/mysql select where id = url id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my script. I have a project page and if you click on one of your project (this is a list of the projects of the user) you go to the project page with project.php?project=id.

The project scipt:

```
                <?php
            require_once 'core/init.php';
            include("header.php");

            ?>

            <?php
            $project = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "' ");
            $project_item = new Projectitem();

            if(!$project->count()) {
                echo 'No Projects';
            } else {

                ?>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <?php
                foreach($project->results() as $project) {

                echo "<tr>";?>
                <td width="9,375em"><img src="<?php echo $project->project_img; ?>"><?php
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";?>   


                <a href="project_item.php?project=<?php echo escape($project->id); ?>"><?php echo escape($project->name); ?></a>

                <?php
                echo "</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
                }
            }

            echo "</table>";
            echo "</div>";

            include("footer.php");
            ?>
```

If you click as exmplain on a project with id 3 you will get the next result:

**project_item.php?project=3**

The project page script:

```
            <?php
        require_once 'core/init.php';
        include("header.php");

        ?>

        <?php
        $project = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM projects  WHERE id = ? ");

        if(!$project->count()) {
            echo 'No Projects';
        } else {

            ?>
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            <?php
            foreach($project->results() as $project) {

            echo "<tr>";?>
            <?php echo "<td>";?>   


            <?php echo escape($project->name); ?>

            <?php
            echo "</td>";
            echo"</tr>";
            }
        }

        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";

        include("footer.php");
        ?>
```

How can i get the right project with the query?

```
SELECT * FROM projects  WHERE id = ? //(the id from the url)
```

Comment: You need to bind the parameter to the query and then execute the query. If you follow the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) you'll have this solved in no time. You're looking for the id in `$_GET['project']` because you're passing the variable via the query string of the URL.

Comment: Can you please help my with the code, need i do something with:

<?php
// Get the keyword from query string
$keyword = $_GET['project'];
// Prepare the command
$project = DB:getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `id` LIKE :keyword");

<?php echo escape($project->name); ?>

Comment: It's hard to parse code dumped into comments. Edit your original post and add the updated information there.